# openGL c++ - text rendering from .png image

Tags: c++, opengl

I downloaded a .png font file and want to write some kind of handler for displaying it. The problem is, that I can not target 1 particular letter I need. When I change the glTexCoord2f values, the texture gets "smaller", but it is always pointed at the middle of my image, not for example at my "A" letter, which is in the top left corner of the image. I tried various glTexCoord2f parameters combinations, but I can not get it to be working. I know that I can "physically" cut out all these letter into separate .pngs, but I want to avoid that, so my project will not get any messier.

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(pos_x, pos_y);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(pos_x, pos_y + h);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(pos_x + w, pos_y);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(pos_x + w, pos_y + h);
glEnd();
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You have to know the dimensions of the glyphs in your texture font, because that texture is really just a packed texture atlas. Usually you use a library like FreeType2 to manage this sort of thing. Wherever you got your font image from should probably have some accompanying information that explains that.

Comment: That's not the problem. It's just that I can't move freely around on my font texture. It's always just set to the centre of it, whether I change the glTexCoords2f to different values or not, so I can't "cut" out any letters I want because of it. I just need to know a way how to bind my texture using only it's little piece for example on it's left upper corner, where the "A" letter is, which I can't do right now, because its' position changed relative to the centre. I hope you understand it, but I don't know how to put it better in english.

Comment: texture coord range from 0.0 to 1.0, so for a small random part of it, coord would be: (0.4,0.5)...I'm pretty sure you are trying integer values above 1 like 2,3,4,5 which are copies of original tex if repeat is on....

Comment: to be more clear, for a 256x256 texture, you access the 50th pixel on x with `1/256 * 50`, idem for y :-)